# Is there a way to update Application Settings from a Web.Config file in an Azure App Service

Tags: azure, application-settings

I am using the Application Setting in an Azure App Service to inject some config variables into the Web.Config, but when I add a new variable into the web.config I need to manually add it into the Application Settings in order to be able to inject against this new variable.

Is there a way to have these Application Settings automatically update in Azure when a new Web.config file is deployed, or is it a manual step specifically to reduce the number of variables which are editable?

Comment: Appears this can be done via Powershell, this article may help. https://codehollow.com/2016/06/automatically-set-azure-app-settings/